# Why Decimal(math.pow(2,60)-1) is NOT equal to Decimal(math.pow(2,60))-Decimal(1)?

Tags: python

The [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic.

I wrote this to learn this module.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 19
print(Decimal(math.pow(2,60)-1))
print(Decimal(math.pow(2,60))-Decimal(1))
```

the weird this is, I got 2 different results.

```
1152921504606846976
1152921504606846975
```

why is that?

**Note** the number is a long integer rather than a float/double

Comment: They use different precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not weird at all. `math.pow(2,60)` will return a float (1.152921504606847e+18) with all the float limitations, such as deducting 1 from this large number will not change the outcome and you use this arithmetic before applying Decimal.

Indeed Using Decimal overcomes this as well as using the `**` instead of math.pow.

```
>>> 2**60
>>> 1152921504606846976
>>> 2**60 - 1
>>> 1152921504606846975
```